# How to get associated portal id of a portal user

Tags: apex, customer-portal

I need to get the portal id of a portal user in apex

I have the userId, but I cannot find a way to get it's portal id

Is that through the User? Profile?

does anyone know?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: I am creating a "log in as portal user" button on the contact record home - for lightning (This capability is not available in lightning). I have developed successfully a lightning component action to do that (open a new url that logs in), and it needs the portal id that is hard coded, and I want it not to be hard coded.

Comment: What's your approach, to form URL same as in `Log in to Community as User` and redirect to it?

Comment: yes, redirect from within my lightning component action - it works good.

Comment: Wrote an answer, hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

**portalId**
From Setup, enter Customer Portal Settings in the Quick Find box, then select Customer Portal Settings
Select a Customer Portal name, and on the Customer Portal detail page, the URL of the Customer Portal displays. The Portal ID is in the URL.
ref: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_header_loginscopeheader.htm

One important thing to note

> The portalID value may be null or an empty key if there is no portal
>   configured with this provider.

ref: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_auth_plugin.htm#apex_Auth_RegistrationHandler_updateUser

Comment: Thanks, but I am asking how to get the portalId from APEX and not from the Salesforce UI

Answer (score 1):

It's quite possible that any give Portal User will have access to multiple Portals (or Communities). You will probably have to get the User's Profile, and Permission Sets, and using those results figure out which Portals (and/or Communities) that User has access to.

It's actually something that you should probably Plan for in advance, IF you intend to support more than one Portal/Community

Comment: How can Salesforce know that portal id of the contact then ? you can see that they have implemented the "Log in as portal user" button on the contact page - for portal contacts?

Comment: If the org has multiple Portals/Communities, when you click that "Log in as..." button it will ask which Portal/Community that you want to log in as. The button will show ALL Portals/Communities to choose from and will only verify that the Contact/User has access when a choice is made.

Comment: I understand, but it wont be a problem for me since I want to SOQL query the sObject (which I cannot find), and then I can decide to which record to login...

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this for classic UI, you need *NetworkId* which represents the Community not which is different than *PortalId*.

> I believe, PortalId is for old customer Portals.

Lets breakdown the URL of `Log in to Community as User` button/link:

> /servlet/servlet.su?
>
> oid={Org Id}&
>
> retURL={Return Url}&
>
> sunetworkid={NetworkId}&
>
> sunetworkuserid={userId}

1. Org Id can be retrieved by: `UserInfo.getOrganizationId()`
2. Network Id can be retrieved by querying [`NetworkMember`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_networkmember.htm) and filtering against the User:

   > SELECT MemberId, NetworkId 
   >       FROM NetworkMember WHERE 
   >       MemberId = userId AND 
   >       Network.Status = 'Live'

   - Status = 'Live' would mean published community, refer [Network](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_network.htm) Object for more details.

---

Now, lets move ahead to code. With collecting pieces together, you can construct URL by following code:

```
public List<String> fetchCommunityLoginUrlForUser(Id userId) {

    List<String> lstCommunityUrls = new List<String>();

    String communityUrlTemplate = '/servlet/servlet.su?' +
        'oid={0}&' +
        'retURL={1}&' +
        'sunetworkid={2}&' +
        'sunetworkuserid={3}';

    for(NetworkMember objNetworkMember: [SELECT MemberId, NetworkId 
        FROM NetworkMember WHERE 
        MemberId = :userId AND 
        Network.Status = 'Live']) {
        lstCommunityUrls.add(String.format(communityUrlTemplate, 
            new List<String> {
                UserInfo.getOrganizationId(),
                'your return URL',
                objNetworkMember.NetworkId,
                objNetworkMember.MemberId
                }));
    }

    System.debug('lstCommunityUrls: ' + lstCommunityUrls);

    System.debug('lstCommunityUrls: ' + lstCommunityUrls);

    return lstCommunityUrls;
}
```

**Result**: This should give you URLs for active communities to which user is part of.

Comment: Thanks @Rahul. Yes - I am using the old portal and I understand now that I need to query the Portal sObject, but I cannot - I get `INVALID_TYPE: sObject type 'Portal' is not supported.` everywhere I try. Also the Network object is returning an INVALID_TYPE error, is there a way to enable these types?